# C++: Is "Virtual" inherited to all descendants

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

Assume the following simple case (notice the location of **virtual**)

```
class A {
    virtual void func();
};

class B : public A {
    void func();
};

class C : public B {
    void func();
};
```

Would the following call call `B::func()` or `C::func()`?

```
B* ptr_b = new C();
ptr_b->func();
```

Comment: yes, declaring a method as virtual makes all its descendants virtual

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Examples using pointers as well as reference.

- Using pointer

  ```
  B *pB = new C();
  pB->func(); //calls C::func()

  A *pA = new C();
  pA->func(); //calls C::func()
  ```
- Using reference. Note the last call: the most important call.

  ```
  C c;
  B & b = c;
  b.func(); //calls C::func() 

  //IMPORTANT - using reference!
  A & a = b;
  a.func(); //calls C::func(), not B::func()
  ```

Online Demo : http://ideone.com/fdpU7

Answer (score 7):

1. Your code is invalid C++. What are the parentheses in class definition?
2. It depends on the dynamic type of the object that is pointed to by `pointer_to_b_type`.
3. If I understand what you *really* want to ask, then 'Yes'. This calls `C::func`:

   ```
   C c;
   B* p = &c;
   p->func();
   ```

Comment: @Amir: he IS asking yes/no question.

Comment: @Amir: "Is “Virtual” inherited to all descendants" sounds like a yes/no question to me.

Comment: @Amir: really? I've always thought that questions of the form "Is ..." and "Would ..." are yes/no questions.

Answer (score 3):

It calls the function in the class that you're referring to. It works it's way up if it doesn't exist, however.

Try the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
    public:
    virtual void func() { cout << "Hi from A!" << endl; }
};

class B : public A {
    public:
    void func()  { cout << "Hi from B!" << endl; }
};

class C : public B {
    public:
    void func()  { cout << "Hi from C!" << endl; }
};

int main() {
  B* b_object = new C;
  b_object->func();
  return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Apologies for that - I completely missed that in his post. Amended. My answer still stands though ;)